# Return only the line containing "Boston", not all lines

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to select only the line containing the word "Boston", but instead of that I get all the lines. Any help please?

```
$posts = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=50"

$posts.posts | %{$_.Content} | Select-String -Pattern "Boston"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find `-match` is easier to implement than `select-string`:

```
$posts = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=50"    
$posts.posts.content.split("`n") -match 'Boston'

<h3 class="story-link"><a href="http://www.bostonmagazine.com/news/article/2014/10/28/jennifer-roberts-iri
sh-black-race-southie/?src=longreads">9. One of Us</a></h3>
<p>Jennifer J. Roberts, <em>Boston Magazine</em></p>
<p>Memories of being a Southie kid and black in a mostly white neighborhood in Boston.</p>
```

Comment: Keep forgetting `-match` is an array operator.

Comment: Thanks mjolinor and Matt

Answer (score 0):

`$_.Content` is one large string. It is not delimited with new lines. This is important since `Select-String`  returns the *whole* string matched. Splitting the string up so it can be processed is one way of getting the results you want. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

> When you pipe more than one string (a "collection") to Select-String, Select-String searches for the specified text in each string and returns each string that contains the search text

```powershell
$posts = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=50"
$posts.posts.content | ForEach-Object{$_.Split("`r`n")} | Select-String -Pattern "Boston"
```

I don't really use `Invoke-RestMethod` much so I don't know if there is a more elegant method.